# CallableStatement.getResultSet() always return null when calling an Oracle function

Tags: oracle, jdbc, callable-statement

I am executing the following code:

```
CallableStatement cs;
cs = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call mypackage.myfunc()}");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
System.out.println(cs.execute());
System.out.println(cs.getResultSet());
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);
System.out.println(rs);
```

The function is declared as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY myuser.mypackage AS 
FUNCTION myfunc
return sys_refcursor 
is 
a_cursor sys_refcursor; 
begin 
open a_cursor for select * from mytable; 
return a_cursor; 
end myfunc; 
end mypackage; 
/
```

According to the documentation, if there is a result then cs.execute() will return true and cs.getResultSet() will have a value. However, this is the output I get:

```
false
null
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@b92a848
```

I am using Oracle Express 11.2.0 and the latest driver.

Any hints/explanations/things to try will be very welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResultSet()` is typically used with `PreparedStatement`s that return data from a SQL `SELECT` query, not with calls to stored procedures or functions.  So I completely expect the `false` and `null` values you are seeing.

If you have a stored procedure that returns one or more ref cursors, then you fetch the values using `getObject` and cast them to `ResultSet`s.  In fact, your code above does exactly this, so I don't understand why you need 'things to try'.

A SQL `SELECT` statement has to send the selected data somewhere, but because you can't put a bind parameter or suchlike into the SQL to act as the destination for the data, you require a separate mechanism for getting access to this data via JDBC.  This is what `getResultSet()` is for.  Your function returns a ref cursor via a bind parameter, so there isn't any need for an implicit 'result', as you can access the data via the bind parameter.

Comment: Hello Luke,

Thank you for the reply.

I am aware that I wouldn't need the getResultSet() call since the parameter is already bound and I can do cs.getObject(1), but I am facing a design issue where I would need getResultSet() to return the cursor (I have no control over this code, that's why - the above code is just to demonstrate what I need to achieve).

So if there's no way for function to actually return the ResultSet via the getResultSet() method (the API is a bit confusing on this regard) I will just simply drop it.

Comment: I don't think the API is that confusing.  Your function happens to return a ref cursor, but what if it returns an number or a string?  What if it has an OUT parameter that returns another ref cursor?  JDBC doesn't attempt to parse the SQL so it won't know that bind parameter 1 is a function's return value.  And even if it could, I don't think that JDBC should make a special case for a function that happens to return a ref cursor.