# stored procedure returns just one row of multiple rows

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I will start by giving you my table content

[image]

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getFoodsForOrder
    (
    @orderID INT,
    @ID INT OUTPUT,
    @food_restaurantID INT OUTPUT,
    @count INT OUTPUT,
    @description VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT
    )
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    SELECT [ID],
    [food_restaurantID],
    [count],
    [description]
    FROM Order_Food
    WHERE orderID = @orderID
END
```

#### My Problem

when I call the stored procedure from JDBC like this

```
Connection con = Database.getConnection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        try {
            callableStatement = con
                    .prepareCall("{call getFoodsForOrder(?,?,?,?,?)}");
            callableStatement.setInt(1, getID());
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            System.out.println("ID   = " + getID());
            boolean haveResult = callableStatement.execute();
            while (haveResult) {
                System.out.println("here I am");
                haveResult = callableStatement.getMoreResults();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (callableStatement != null)
                    callableStatement.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

it just print `here I am` once, just once, even If (like the picture said) I have more than 15 rows are ture.

you problem will ask me if I am sure about the `getID()` method, Yes I am sure and even when I replace it with explicit 10 , the result doesn't change.

#### Something might help

when I call that stored procedure from my Visual studio , I got 17 results like this:

[image]

#### Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I guess it is related to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505812/resultset-nullpointerexception ; if you want to process as a resultset, don't use `OUTPUT` parameters. The `CallableStatement` part for output parameters seems to be designed for processing a single result.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that question didnt help me , I just made it accepted because I want t start a new thread

Comment: pleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaase help

Answer (score 3):

The `callableStatement.execute()` indicates **if** a result set is available.

`getMoreResults()` only indicates if there are is *another* **ResultSet** available, not if the "last" result set has more rows (which is - I think - pretty clear from the JavaDocs). `getMoreResults()` would return `true` if you had more than one `select` statement in your procedure.

If `execute()` indicates a ResultSet *is* available you need to obtain it using `callableStatement.getResultSet()` and then iterate over the rows returned by that.

Something like:

```
boolean haveResult = callableStatement.execute();
if (haveResult) {
   ResultSet rs = callableStatement.getResultSet();
   while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
   }
} else {
  System.out.println("Nothing returned");
}
```

But as you **know** it returns a result set you can also call `getResultSet()` right away without even bothering about the return value of the `execute()` call.

Comment: you used my exact code, nothing new you add, i still can't find a solution , would you help me please

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: no I did not use "your code". Please read my explanation on what the return value of the `execute()` call means. Plus you do not have a `getResult()` anywhere in your code. `getResult()` is something **completely** different than `getMoreResult()` which you are using. Please read the JavaDocs for those methods carefully. That difference is the part that will make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `OUTPUT` variables from your stored procedure and no longer register them in your code. You then need to use `executeQuery()` to get the resultset and iterate over the resultset to get rows.

Assuming a table structure of:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order_Food](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderID] [int] NULL,
    [food_restaurantID] [int] NULL,
    [count] [int] NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Order_Food] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Table content:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order_Food] 
     ([OrderID], [food_restaurantID], [count], [description])
     VALUES (513, 2, 3, 'Description xyz'), (513, 2, 3, 'Description xyz'), 
        (132, 1, 2, 'Description abc');
```

A stored procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getFoodsForOrder
    (
    @orderID INT
    )
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    SELECT [ID],
    [food_restaurantID],
    [count],
    [description]
    FROM Order_Food
    WHERE orderID = @orderID
END
```

And query code as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try (
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Scratchspace;integratedSecurity=true");
        CallableStatement callableStatement = 
            con.prepareCall("{call getFoodsForOrder(?)}");
    ){
        callableStatement.setInt(1, 513);
        System.out.println("ID   = " + 513);
        ResultSet rs = callableStatement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.printf("%d %d %d %s%n",
                    rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getInt("food_restaurantID"),
                    rs.getInt("count"), rs.getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On my computer this produces the output:

```
ID   = 513
1 2 3 Description xyz
2 2 3 Description xyz
```

Comment: I got this exception when debugging your code: `Parameter ID was not defined for stored procedure getFoodsForOrder2.`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I will test it further tonight and let you know

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I tested it and my original code worked except for minor modifications to fix obvious syntax errors (like forgetting `()` after `next`) and removing some reference to parts of your code I didn't have. I have now updated my answer with the table, content, stored procedure and code I executed on my machine against SQL Server 20102 using the SQL Server JDBC version 4.0 driver. I also used the Java 7 try-with-resources in the updated code