# Java DOM XML Parser - printed XML contains one tag instead of multiple ones

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, transformation

I have written some code loading records from MySQL and parsing them and saving into XML file. What I wanted to achieve was somethin like this:

```
<part><row>.....</row><row>...</row></part>
```

Now I have:

```
<part><row>...</row></part>
```

Here is screen showing my poroblem:

[image]

Here is Java code section which parses data into XML `Document` structure:

```
private void callSPInParOrWithout(final Document doc, 
            final Connection conn) {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        try {
            // <part>
            Element part = doc.createElement("part");
            doc.appendChild(part);

            cs = conn.prepareCall("{CALL getBrandRows(?)}");
            cs.setString(1, "Brand#13");

            boolean results = cs.execute();
            while (results) {
                // <row>
                Element row = doc.createElement("row");
                part.appendChild(row);   
                rs = cs.getResultSet();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    // <p_partkey>
                    Element pPartKey = doc.createElement("p_partkey");
                    pPartKey.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(
                            rs.getInt("p_partkey"))));
                    row.appendChild(pPartKey);
                    // <p_name>
                    Element pName = doc.createElement("p_name");
                    pName.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(rs.getString(
                            "p_name")));
                    row.appendChild(pName);
                    // <p_mfgr>   
                    Element pMfgr = doc.createElement("p_mfgr");
                    pMfgr.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(rs.getString(
                            "p_mfgr")));
                    row.appendChild(pMfgr);
                    // <p_brand>
                    Element pBrand = doc.createElement("p_brand");
                    pBrand.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(rs.getString(
                            "p_brand")));
                    row.appendChild(pBrand);
                    // <p_type>
                    Element pType = doc.createElement("p_type");
                    pType.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(rs.getString(
                            "p_type")));
                    row.appendChild(pType);
                    // <p_size>
                    Element pSize = doc.createElement("p_size");
                    pSize.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(
                            rs.getInt("p_size"))));
                    row.appendChild(pSize);
                    // <p_container>
                    Element pContainer = doc.createElement("p_container");
                    pContainer.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(rs.getString(
                            "p_container")));
                    row.appendChild(pContainer);
                    // <p_retailprice>
                    Element pRetailPrice = doc.createElement("p_retailprice");
                    pRetailPrice.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(
                            Float.toString(rs.getFloat("p_retailprice"))));
                    // <p_comment>
                    Element pComment = doc.createElement("p_comment");
                    pComment.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(rs.getString(
                            "p_comment")));
                    row.appendChild(pComment);
                }
                results = cs.getMoreResults();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), 
                    "Exception occured", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) rs.close();
                if (cs != null) cs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the screenshot it works well but I made some mistake with creating `<row>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the `row` element only once, before iterating over all the rows in the ResultSet.

To get the expected result, create the `row` element inside the `while (rs.next())` loop, and move `part.appendChild(row);` to the end of that loop's body.

`CallableStatement#execute()` indicates if a result set is available. `CallableStatement#getMoreResults()` indicates if another result set is available; there is no use in calling it unless your statement returns multiple result sets (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16523681/4442714)). If your CallableStatement returns only one result set, you can safely use an `if` in place of the outer `while`, and remove the call to `getMoreResults()`.